# Why do the new ranges remove_* algorithms move the first iterator?

Tags: c++, c++20, std

I was reading through the MSVC STL implementation of `std::ranges::remove` when I noticed the following line:

```cpp
_First = _RANGES _Find_if_unchecked(_STD move(_First), _Last, _Pred, _Proj);
```

Indeed, [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/remove) has the following line in their 'possible implementation' too:

```cpp
first = ranges::find_if(std::move(first), last, pred, proj);
```

What's confusing to me is, I've just about never seen anyone move an iterator; they're typically cheap to copy (or at least should be), and even if this were an issue of copies, we could take a universal reference and `std::forward` the iterator to `find_if` instead surely?

What advantage does casting to an rvalue reference have here over simply passing by value?

Comment: *Typically* cheap doesn't mean that you can ignore that cases where they aren't. These also need to handle any user-defined iterators.

Comment: @molbdnilo true, but the old std::remove_* doesn't move here, even though it would be non-breaking to do so. I might be wrong, but I don't think the cost of copying is the issue here

Comment: *"they're typically cheap to copy (or at least should be)"* - It's pretty bad form to miss an obvious optimization opportunity because things "should be" some way. There is absolutely no downside to the move, only benefits to certain outlying cases.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica okay, so does that mean the old std::remove_* algorithms are just missing an opportunity to optimise that the new algorithms didn't?

Comment: Can you give a link to cppreference? The code you quote does not exist in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/find .

Comment: @zkoza this is on the remove page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/remove

Comment: Very probably. They predate move semantics, and I know for a fact they weren't all reviewed for possible improvements. You can see a particularly interesting anecdote of it here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOSirVeP5lo (and the [algorithm in question](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) *was* updated in c++20).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ranges::find_if` accepts `input_iterator`, which is not necessarily `copyable` (an example in the standard is [`basic_istream_view::iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/basic_istream_view/iterator)).

In the C++20 iterator system, only iterators that model [`forward_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/forward_iterator) are guaranteed to be copyable, so `std::move` is *necessary* here.

> and even if this were an issue of copies, we could take a universal
> reference and std::forward the iterator to find_if instead surely?

Iterators are generally passed by value.

When the `first` iterator is not guaranteed to be copyable, we need to transfer its ownership to `ranges::find_if` via `std::move`, and re-accept its ownership via its return.

(Although in your example `std::move` can be omitted since `ranges::remove` already requires `forward_iterator`)